# How to construct Google Cloud SQL JDBC URL for SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

The best documentation I have been able to find about how to create a JDBC URL for an SQL Server instance within Cloud SQL is located here:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory

The only problem is, there is no example or instructions for creating the JDBC URL for SQL Server.

I have tried some obvious possible solutions, none of which have worked - for example:

```
jdbc:sqlserver:///<DATABASE_NAME>;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.sqlserver.SocketFactory;cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>;user=<USER_NAME>;password=<PASSWORD>
```

I have a mysql server in the same project that I am able to connect to with no issue (after updating the jdbc Driver and JDBC URL).  SQL Admin API is enabled and GOOGLE_APPLICATOIN_CREDENTIALS is pointing to the correct service account.

Relevant pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>cloud-sql-connector-jdbc-sqlserver</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>8.4.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
```

If i'm reading the git repo correctly it actually looks like JDBC support for SQL Server was just added in the 1.2.0 release - has anyone been able to get this to work?
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/pull/263

Error I am receiving

```
ERROR: The TCP/IP connection to the host /<DATABASE_NAME>, port 1433 has failed. Error: "/<DATABASE_NAME>. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with [R2DBC](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#instructions-for-r2dbc). There are specific instructions as to what to modify on your [pom.xml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#sql-server-1) and the [connection URL](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#sql-server-2). Also from where exactly (GAE, GCE, local computer) are you trying to connect to the instance? Are you using the Cloud SQL proxy?

Comment: It seems as if you are trying to make a TCP connection through the typical 1433 port used by SQL Server, but if you are e.g. using the Cloud SQL proxy the connection will be performed by using a [Unix Socket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#connection-via-unix-sockets) and you'd need to make sure to allow connections on port 3307 on your [Firewall](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory#firewall-configuration).

Comment: @DanielOcando Thiis is from a local computer.  I am using cloud proxy.  I can see that a connection is opened and then closed after the connection fails
`2021/01/14 21:07:34 New connection for "<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>"
2021/01/14 21:07:37 Client closed local connection on 127.0.0.1:1433`

Comment: Is it a Windows or Unix based computer? Take into consideration that the [Cloud SQL Proxy does not support Unix Sockets on Windows](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#proxy_startup_options)

Comment: @DanielOcando this is from a windows machine.  I am able to connect via Cloud Proxy to a mysql Cloud SQL instance in the same project without issue (simply by changing the driver and jdbc url) so I don't think the problem here is Unix Sockets / firewall.

Comment: There is a specific example on the docs you refer to [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/sqlserver/servlet) you could check how the JDBC URL is built from this [line of code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/aa5a1ef0577b9bdd0acc03f300c9707b5dfc70d9/cloud-sql/sqlserver/servlet/src/main/java/com/example/cloudsql/ConnectionPoolContextListener.java#L48) in order to build a Connection Pool (which I strongly encourage you to follow as advised [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/manage-connections#java)).

Comment: Let me know if the comment above is useful. As per the docs the connection string should be something like: `jdbc:sqlserver://;user=<DB_USER>;password=<DB_PASS>;databaseName=<DB_NAME>;socketFactoryClass=com.google.cloud.sql.sqlserver.SocketFactory;socketFactoryConstructorArg=<CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME>`.

Comment: @DanielOcando - Thanks for your assistance on this.  I was able to figure out the root cause and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was that the version of `SQLServerDriver` I was using does not appear to compatible with `com.google.cloud.sql.sqlserver.SocketFactory`.  I was able to switch to the `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` which worked as expected.  More info in this thread:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/issues/373